# pairing a Duotrap sensor the the ibike Newton

Tags: road-bike, bike-computer, sensor

Is a Duo-trap speed/cadence sensor compatible with an I-bike Newton head unit? I can't make it pair up. I've tried keeping it a decent distance from other sensors and have tried resetting it, and changing batteries.

Comment: Theres a bunch of duotrap sensors; not all of them have the same feature set. But, a lot of them are ANT+.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the receiving end has ANT+ or Bluetooth Smart, also known as, Bluetooth low energy (BTLE) capability, the DuoTrap works fine. I have been using it with my Android phone for the last 2 years.

If your head unit is BTLE capable, that is enough. You do not need to pair as any other bluetooth device (e.g. BT headset) that would require pairing. The Bluetooth Smart devices sometimes actually do not pair as a regular bluetooth device.

You might need to try multiple times in order for DuoTrap to show up. Try rotating the tires for 10-15 rotations which should invoke the DuoTrap. Once it is active, it would appear on your phone or the head unit. Sometimes it requires 5 - 6 trials.